# Portable executable for CMake

Tags: binary, cmake, portable-executable

I am developing on a Windows machine for which I don't have administrative privileges.
I would like to use CMake to compile, and I cannot simply download and install this due to administrative restrictions.

I would also like to avoid compiling CMake from source (if possible). Are there portable binaries available for Windows that would allow one to simply use CMake?

Comment: why are you avoiding building cmake?  Why don't you just get admin privileges on your development machine or ask your admin to install it?

Comment: I'm in a school setting, so getting admin privileges is not possible.

Answer (score 17):

You can download a ZIP file of CMake. You can just uncompress it somewhere you are allowed to copy files and use it from there. Check the [download page of CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html).