# Link cmake to visual studio's cmake tools

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

Im sorry for the bad title but I just don't know how to put this in the title, so if you do, please remove this line and update the title.

So Im trying to create a portable version of cmake (that doesnt needs admin rights) and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715924/portable-executable-for-cmake) but the awnser only helped me getting cmake itself in a different location. Cmake also needs MSVS's (Microsoft Visual Studio's) Cmake tools to get it to work.

My question is where are these tools located, and can I copy them to a USB stick and make it so cmake uses the tools on the usb stick?

I thought that maybe I could make a batch file that sets a local variable to the tools on the usb stick and then start cmake so cmake knows where the tools are located, but I don't know if cmake even uses Environment Variables.

Any help would be greatly appreaciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple points in your question that are unclear.

## Portable CMake

With downloading the ZIP file of CMake you already "made CMake portable". Just unzip and run it.
CMake has an internal logic to detect installed Visual Studio versions and the compiler.

## CMake Variants

#### Original

To use CMake with the MSVC compiler (or provided by Visual Studio) you do not need anything special from MSVC/VS. CMake uses the informations of the detected MSVC/Visual Studio to generate the project files, etc.

#### Visual Studio's CMake Variant

Visual Studio provides a version of CMake upon installation. To use your portable CMake variant you do not need anything from there.

### Force a specific VS Generator

If you have only one Visual Studio installed then CMake will use this. If you have multiple Visual Studios installed normally CMake uses the newest one. In case you want to force a specific Version you can specifiy the CMake generator to use [cmake-generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html).

Another way would be to use the `vcvarsall.bat` or `vsdevcmd.bat` to setup the environment for a specific Visual Studio version and run CMake from that environment.

## Finally

It is sufficient to have the original CMake release (from the ZIP file) on your USB stick. But it is not possible to provide a portable MSVC (Microsoft Visual Compiler) on your USB stick (as far as I know) as it has to be installed.